# Barcode in PDF not displaying in FireFox

Tags: java, firefox, pdf-generation, barcode, itext7

We're facing a strange issue . I generated a PDF via `iText 7`. That PDF opens perfectly on my and tester's system. (We both are in India). Even on our personal machine it's fine. We tested it on all below:

1. Adobe Reader
2. FireFox
3. Chrome

Whereas, our other team team members (who are in Brussels) can open the PDF in Chrome and Adobe Reader, but in FireFox the PDF opens but does not display the barcode. Even this issue is on there personal
laptops.

- Both version of FireFox are the same: `80.0.1 64-bit`.

Only geography is different, rest settings/version are all same.
Why would this be?

Edit :
**Code for generating barcode:**

```
public static String getBarCodeImage(String barCode, boolean drawingText) throws OutputException, BarcodeException, IOException {

    Barcode barcode = null;

    if(isNumeric(barCode)){
        barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128C(barCode);
    }else {
        barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(barCode);
    }

    barcode.setBarHeight(34);
    barcode.setBarWidth(157);
    barcode.setDrawingText(false);

    BufferedImage image =  BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

**Pdf Generation code:**

```
public static byte[] createPdf(List<String> htmlPages, PageSize pageSize, boolean rotate) throws IOException {

    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();

          org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register();
    properties.setBaseUri("classpath:/");
    
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, false);
    properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
    writerProperties.useSmartMode();
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream, writerProperties));
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);

    for (String htmlPage : htmlPages) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos, writerProperties));
        if (rotate) {
            temp.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize.rotate());
        } else {
            temp.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
        }
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlPage, temp, properties);
        temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
        merger.merge(temp, 1, temp.getNumberOfPages());
        temp.close();
    }
    pdf.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

**Screenshot of pdf:**
[image]

[image]
you can find html file [here](https://github.com/amolbais05/barcode) for it

One observation i made that, if bar-code text is of length 8, it work's in both geography.

Comment: Please share an example PDF output for analysis. I cannot run your code because you only mention iText 7 as involved library which does not include your `BarcodeFactory` and `BarcodeImageHandler` classes; furthermore, one apparently needs to run your code in a web application (considering the `TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory`) which means quite a bit of setup just for being able to reproduce your issue...

Comment: Hi @mkl , i am not using `BarcodeFactory` or `BarcodeImageHandler` for setting barcode to  html file, I am just replacing $barCodeImage in `src="data:image/png;base64,$barCodeImage"` with `base64` encoded string. I added pdf and some files to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63507162/1729265) the bitmap is unnecessarily gigantic in its width while having a reasonable height: 24178×34. You should really switch to sensible widths. But as an aside, Firefox here (version 72.0.2) properly displays the barcode.

Comment: Thank you @mkl , it worked after setting width as 68, But still I am curious, why barcode image was rendering in India and not in Belgium (for firefox), that really made us crazy for replication.

Comment: Have you made sure you use the same Firefox versions?

Comment: @mkl yes, version is same, even the system configuration is same.